# ASP.NET MVC Loading Foreign Key Collection after Update - strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Index view displaying a list of items, with a collection of assignments for each one. Everything displays property the first time the view is loaded. When I edit an item and add or remove assignments, the changes are reflected correctly in the data (and on the Edit view), but the Index view now shows an incorrect number of assignments. I think this has something to do with lazy loading and the way I'm retrieving data, but I'm not positive.

Model:

```
public Int64 ID { get; set; }
public string Title {get; set;}
...
public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
```

Function GetItemsForUser() (this always returns the data I'm expecting from the DB):

```
var items = from w in db.ItemRepository
    join a in db.AssignmentRepository on w.ID equals a.ItemID into sAssign
    from assign in sAssign.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select w;
...
return items.Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.Priority).ThenByDescending(o => o.Deadline).ToList();
```

In the controller:

```
IEnumerable<Item> wi = GetItemsForUser();
```

At this point, when inspect the contents of wi in the debugger, the Assignments collection is incorrect. For example, I had 2 initial assignments, and then added and removed a bunch for testing (ending up with four assignments). Under Assignments, I now see two entries for System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Assignments. Then I have eight more that are listed as MyApp.Models.Assignment - those are the ones I was adding and deleting. What I expect is to see four items, all with the type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Assignments.

I believe this has something to do with how I'm retrieving the data in GetItemsForUser(), when I selected items.Distinct() (and possibly to do with how lazy loading works). It's as if it's not refreshing the contents of the Assignments collection from the database, and I need to be able to force it to always update that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you, as a point of comparison, looked up the equivalent row(s) in the datastore? You might be looking at cached data.

Comment: Yes, I checked that and it's correct. The only way to get the list of items to display correctly once I've started changing assignments is to kill the debug session and restart it.

Comment: Are you always using the same instance of `db` in `GetItemsForUser()` but different instance(s) to do the updates?

Comment: If you're using a class-level EF context, don't. New up a new one (or inject it per request) in each action, which will make sure you're always getting fresh data.

Comment: No, the instances are different. The updates occur using the one in the controller, and GetItemsForUser() is in another class. Each has:

   private WTContext db = new WTContext();

Would the context itself be retaining that data? I'm not entirely sure how that works.

Comment: OK, I tested it with a new context for each action, rather than using the ones defined at the class level, and that worked! Time to do some rewriting.

Thanks again for the advice... if you can leave your reply as an answer I can accept it as the correct solution.